# IMAPI: What is the difference between get_MediaPhysicallyBlank and get_MediaHeuristicallyBlank?

Tags: imapi

From the MSDN documentation of [get_MediaHeuristicallyBlank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365374(VS.85).aspx) and [get_MediaPhysicallyBlank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365375(VS.85).aspx), it is not clear what is the exact difference between these two.
Can anyone please explain how both of these are different?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for same difference but could not find one. What I learned is as below.

`get_MediaHeuristicallyBlank`

IMAPI scans media to check if it is blank. This may be bit longer call.

`get_MediaPhysicallyBlank`

IMAPI asks drive if the media is blank. Drive returns the status and IMAPI relies on it. This may be shorter call than the above.

In my application, I am using `get_MediaHeuristicallyBlank` and I have no any issue.

By the way, I work with C#; NOT C++. But IMAPI interface is same so that should not be an issue.